# How to send JSON integer for text input in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I have a simple text input that I want to send as an integer to the server in JSON format:

```
<input ng-model="album.release_year" pattern="\d{4}" placeholder="YYYY" class="text" type="text" required>
```

The problem is this keeps sending it as `'1995'` instead of `1995`.

I've changed the input type to `"number"` except then the problem is all my validations break (for some reason it lets you submit a form that doesnt follow the pattern).

Comment: input has `type="text"` so you get text. To send it as Integer try to create directive and parse `ng-model`

Comment: No attempt has been transforming the value as text to numbers? the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [formatters and parsers](http://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html) - they are used for exactly things like these. Parsers change how the value from the view will be stored in the model. While formatters change how the value from the model will be displayed in the view.

Using a directive you could do something like this:

```
<input ng-model="album.release_year"
       my-input-directive
       pattern="\d{4}" placeholder="YYYY"
       class="text" type="text" 
       required>
```

And create a directive, adding a parser to the ngModel

```
angular.module('my.module', [])
    .directive('myInputDirective', function(){
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){
                    return parseInt(viewValue);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: @Tallboy just curious, you said "Amazing" but didn't upvote your solution. Maybe, like me, you reached your daily limit.

Comment: I marked it as the answer, which awards lots of points. If it's the only answer in the post, and its the correct one, upvoting it doesn't have a purpose because it's not competing with any other answers.